# Efficient way to select rows from sqlite table having a million rows

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I have an sqlite table which consists of about a million rows having three columns which are :
id | word | meaning |

Its for a dictionary app where the user searches for a word and a query is performed on that table to retrieve rows having such word (multiple rows might be returned).

But the problem is that the query is painfully slow, it takes about 30 seconds to return a result.

Is there a way to speed up the retrieval by using a different query?

PS: all rows are already ordered by alphabetically by word and numerically by id, I wonder if I can speed up the retrieval by specifying where to query eg between "rabbit" and "rock" etc. But I don't know what query or method to use.

Here's my query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM entries WHERE lower(word) =:word") List<Entry> getAllEntriesForWord(String word);
```

Comment: Why `lower()`? Without this function and with an index on `word` you would get the best  possible performance.

Comment: Some similar words might be in both upper and lowercase. I've just read a bit on indexing, I don't quite get it but I'll look further into it.

Comment: as forpas mentioned those two changes will be a great improvement in performance. What you can do is lower the word first and then pass it as a parameter to the query so to avoid calling lower() every time. Alternatively you can add 'collate nocase' in your where clause to make it case insensitive.

Comment: I've used collate no case while recreating my table (seems it's more efficient that way) and I've also used an index on word. The performance is still laggy but a lot better than the previous one. Is there anything I can still do or are theses the only options I have?

Comment: not much more you can do in this query. Other things are improving SQLlite DB performance by adjusting log, temp storage, etc, and the other thing would be try another approach, like divide and conquer by separate the table into 2 lets say, from A to M and N to Z and then determining in which one to search depending on the first letter of the search argument

Comment: That's exactly what I did. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: @HaleemahAbdullahi can you please share code snippest. how you are diving and conquer in database. i am struggling with same scenario.